# How to download updated files from SharePoint in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have over 100 files in SharePoint location which I ingest and process daily using ADF and Databricks. Not all files are updated daily and I end up wasting my time and resources by processing unchanged files. How can I download files which are updated?

My pipeline does not run on weekends whereas there can be updates in SharePoint files in weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put an additional .md5 file to the location which contains the md5 digest of your file, or other summary information suitable for you pipeline to process. Then your pipeline can choose to skip processing unchanged file(s).